# Error with if [ -n $diffCurr ]: Too many arguments

Tags: diff, test

I have been using the below code ok for some time, but now I get an error

```
java Editor < "input/editor$i.in" > "tmp/editor$i.out"
diffCurr="$(diff "tmp/editor$i.out" "output/editor$i.out")"
if [ -n $diffCurr ]
```

Error (occurs on last line of above snippet):

> [: too many arguments

What's wrong? I am trying to test that the diff result was empty (ie. same contents in file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need to put the output of `diff` in a variable, since you can tell whether files differ based on the exit status of `diff`, e.g.

```
if diff -q file1 file2 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # files are equal
else
        # files differ, or an error occurred
fi
```

`diff` returns success (`0`) if the files do not differ.  Adjust the logic as necessary.

Testing exit statuses of commands when possible is almost always preferred over checking or parsing output via command substitution.

For the sake of completeness, the error with your original example happened because you didn't quote `"$diffCurr"` in the `if` line, so it went through "word splitting" into more than one word --- hence "too many arguments".

Comment: what does `2>&1` do?

Comment: The redirections on the end (`>/dev/null 2>&1`) serve to hide the output of `diff`.  `2>&1` redirects stderr to the same place as stdout, which was earlier in the same line sent to `/dev/null` (a virtual black hole).

Comment: Sorry, I still dont really get it. I understand the 1st part `diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null` as having output redirected to `/dev/null`. But does 2 mean any errors from diff to /dev/null (represented by &1 in this case?) too?

Comment: If you are only interested in the output you can replace `diff` with `cmp` ...

Comment: @jiewmeng that is correct

Comment: @jw013, looking back at this post. I dont really get the part `2>&1`. Where can I find more info on that? In a "generic" command, what does `2` and `&1` refer to? For that matter, I have have `1>&2` what does that refer to?

Comment: @jiewmeng - 2 and 1 are file descriptors; 1 is standard out and 2 is standard error. The '>' character is for redirection. This is a fairly thorough explanation [http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html]. I also came to add that, if you are interested in the output of the diff command, you could also continue to use the variable assignment and modify your if expression to be [ $? ]. This is functionally equivalent to jw013's suggestion but maintains the variable storage.

Comment: @jiewmeng That's the "copy descriptor" operator. There's some good information about it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/copydescriptor).

Comment: @jiewmeng I think Chris and Tok have answered your question about the meaning of `2>&1` fairly well.

Answer (score 10):

jw013 is right, you don't need this line anyway.

But to answer the actual question, you have left out quotation marks around the variable that you passed into `test` (otherwise known as `[`).

This means if your variable is empty, it will be as if you had no arguments (eg `[ -n ]`), and if your variable contains spaces, it will be as if you passed multiple arguments (I'm guessing this is what happened).

Always wrap the strings under `test` with quotes, eg:

```
if [ -n "$myvar" ]
```

Comment: "This line" may be needed if the output is to be sent somewhere, say through `mail` or to `dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to test the exit code of the `diff` command than the output.

```
diffCurr="$(diff "tmp/editor$i.out" "output/editor$i.out")"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  # different
...
```

If you are not interested in the output, then you can do as jw013 suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers above:  My love/hate relationship with bash is focused primarily around its strength in parameter substitution and in the fact that getting it to stop substituting when you want it to can be quite challenging - especially when a variable gets used or altered more than once.

As a result, I almost always code variable references like:

```
A="${B}"
```

This makes sure `B` gets treated as a single string (most often what I want) and it allows things like

```
A="${B}foo"
```

to work as well as a bunch of other fancy options that only work inside the braces.

If I code even a simple safe variable reference as

```
A="${B}"
```

to start with, I'm a lot safer when I go back in to modify the code later and possibly do something that might fail if the quotes or braces were missing.